# Restore Production Content DB to TEST

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database, restore

I restored a production database to Test database (same db name in prod and test). The site collections on the test are already using the same db. Are there additional steps after restoring the prod db to test?

Answer (score 2):

1. Backup SharePoint Production content databases, Restore them into test environment SQL Server instance.
2. Identify and take a list of your source content databases either from Central Administration (Central Administration  ->  Application Management  ->  Manage Content Databases )
3. Or use this PowerShell cmdlet to retrieve all content databases of a particular web application:

   ```
   Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication http://SiteName | Select Name
   ```
4. Backup Databases from SharePoint Production SQL Server
5. Restore Database on SharePoint Test envoriment SQL box:
6. Verify content databases with Test-SPContentDatabase
   PowerShell Command:

   ```
   Test-SPContentDatabase -Name <Database name> -WebApplication <Web-App-URL>
   ```

this would report potential issues such as: Missing Features & Solution dependencies, Orphaned Sites, wide Lists, etc. Resolve Migration issues reported by Test-SPContentDatabase.

7.Detached the Content database, from SharePoint test envoriment Web Application.using PowerShell command

```
Dismount-SPContentDatabase  ContentDatabaseID


Dismount-SPContentDatabase  4e0aa7de-04bc-4a78-a68c-00bd2587f872
```

8.  Attach Content Databases to SharePoint Test envoriment by running:

Mount-SPContentDatabase

```
 Mount-SPContentDatabase “contentdbname” –DatabaseServer “SQLserver” –  
  WebApplication http://SiteName
```

e.g.:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content_24c759078e844a5dad9b132112f0b696 -
DatabaseServer pc5\SHAREPOINT -WebApplication http://pc5:11186/
```

9.Upgrade Site Collections to move them into SharePoint test environment.

a.    One more step to complete our migration: Upgrading site collections. By 
       default, after migrating from production environment to SharePoint test,

b.    At Site Collection Level, you can make use of Site Collection Health
        Checkup: New in SharePoint 2013, Site collection Administrators can 
        perform health checkup at site collection level before upgrading site
        collections from SharePoint 2013 mode to SharePoint 2014! Navigate to

c.    Site Settings ->  Site Collection Administration -> Site collection 
        health checks
  d.    Or Power-Shell command

```
Test-SPSite -identity <URL>
```

e.    Site collection health checkup report gives customized files, missing 
        galleries, missing Content Types, content type conflicts, missing site 
       templates, unsupported language packs, etc. You can repair some of the 
       issues by running:

```
Repair-SPSite -identity <URL>
```

10. Deploy all the WSP files on SharePoint test environment
11. To upgrade the site collections

    ```
     Get-SPSite -contentdatabase WSS_Content -limit All | Upgrade-SPSite -
     versionUpgrade
    ```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the same site collection in the Test Farm, you should detach that content DB from the web app before attaching the Prod restored db. If you attach both DBs to the web app then site will not work.

I would do with the following ways.( i am assuming both farms version level is same, you already deploy the same Customization in test farm[if any], authentication method is same.

- Backup the Prod Database
- Restore it in Test farm sql server
- Detach Existing the DB from the Web App
- Attached newly restored DB to the web app.